# How do I cause WKWebView to execute webView:didFailNavigation?

Tags: ios, webview, wkwebview

I'm writing a wrapper component for WKWebView and I'd like to make sure I cover my bases for error handling.

[The documentation for `webView:didFailNavigation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455623-webview?language=objc) simply states `Called when an error occurs during navigation.` What exactly does the documentation writer mean when they say "navigation?"

I'm aware that there's also `webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation`, which executes whenever there's a loading error. [The documentation for that hook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455637-webview?language=objc) states `Called when an error occurs while the web view is loading content.` I can make this trigger by calling `[_webView loadRequest:request]`, where `request` contains a malformed URL.

Comment: "What exactly does the documentation writer mean when they say "navigation?"" Like, the user clicks on a link, or goes forward or back in the list of previously visited URLs.